# Can we get rid access array in each module in YII2?

Tags: yii2, rbac, access-rules

1) I want to hold all of my restrictions in DB instead of rbac/rules.php, because I dont want to define access array in each module or controller

2) I want some GUI interface for managing my Roles and Groups

Is there are some builkt in modules for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
[RBAC Management Admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)